# Find filenames with certain pattern on Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

Trying to find any files of certain pattern in a directory and its subdirectories.
I tried:

```
C:\test\workspace>dir *.*.r[0-9]* /s /b
File Not Found
```

in hopes to find files like

```
abc.txt.r12222
tjy.java.r9994
```

Where an number is appended after the letter r, done by SVN.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SU! On stackexchange sites, when an answer has helped you, the way to thanking people is to upvote their answer and to accept it (by clicking on the checkmark to the left of an answer) if it solved your problem. I'm only saying because you seem to have accepted none of the answers you have received for your questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just answered this on Stack Overflow a couple of days ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648679/find-text-string-or-part-of-text-with-dot-in-grepwin/15648872#15648872

In your case, it would look like:

```
dir * /s/b | findstr \.r[0-9]*[0-9]$
```

**Updates**

Be careful, the * in one of the other examples ( ".r[0-9]*$") finds all or none of the number range [0-9], so it also finds records that end in 'r' only which is not expected.

My original answer used a RegEx + after the number, but as @ScottChu pointed out, [that's not an option in `findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr).

This answer was also updated with a variant of the comment by @ndreisg which also works, however, the `$` is still needed at the end to ensure the match closes with the number and doesn't find it in the middle of the string.

**WSL**

Also, in addition to installing [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/), you can now install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

Comment: Hi cpattersonv1 - thanks for responding dir * /s /b | findstr \.r[0-9]*$ works

Comment: findstr seems doesn't recognize the 1 or many symbol '+'

Comment: findstr doesn't recognize the + quantifier. I used `[0-9][0-9]*` instead

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for you is to do that with `grep` - an utility for UNIX-like systems that has been ported to Windows and can match lines using regular expressions.

`grep` is included with MinGW's MSYS package, the installer can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/). (install only MSYS)

Then you'll have to add MSYS tools to your PATH variable, dafeult directory for MSYS is `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`

Finally you can do your serach with this command:

```
ls -a | grep ^.+\..+\.r[0-9]+$
```

... which means: "get output from `ls -a` (file listing including hidden files) and pass it to `grep`, match lines that look like *.*.r[0-9]* (with at least one character symbolized by each asterisk)".

Comment: hi gronostaj thanks for the response; I tried `$ ls -R | grep -H ^.*[0-9]$
(standard input):res.jar.r469621
(standard input):res.jar.r464460
(standard input):test.jar.r46521
(standard input):test.jar.r46970`

Comment: Hi I still cant get the full path name of the filename; how do I do that ? eg `c:\pager\test.jar.r46521` as opposed to (standard input):test.jar.r46521

Comment: ls | grep is the same as dir | findstr in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by navigating to c:\windows\system32 where the findstr is located and then execute the suggested commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dir /a| findstr .r[0-9]*$
```

For help, type `findstr /?`.

Comment: Hi mfm4aa thanks for responding - cant seem to work; I've tried all combinations and none gives ant listed answer: Eg inline `C:\Temp>findstr /S /B [0-9] .
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B r[0-9]$ .
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B $.*r[0-9]$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B $.*r*$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B $.*r..*$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B $.*r\..*$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R $.*r\..*$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$.*\..r[0-9]*$
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$.*\..r[0-9]*$"
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$.*\..r[0-9]*$" .
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$.*\..r[0-9]$" .
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$.*[0-9]*" .
C:\Temp>findstr /S /B /R "$*[0-9]*" .`

Comment: Please try: `C:\Temp>dir /aa| findstr .r[0-9]*$`

Comment: Hi mfm thanks for writing - i still cant find `C:\Temp>dir /aa | findstr .r[0-9]*$
File Not Found`

Comment: :) simply type `dir /aa| findstr .r[0-9]*$`. That does working here...

Comment: Hi Endoro thanks for responding. It didn't work - it says File Not Found

Comment: OK, made an edit and added a picture.

Comment: In this answer, `.r[0-9]*$` matches any character followed by the letter "r" that is possibly followed zero or more number characters at the end of the match string. By not escaping the period, it will match many more files (E.g., .rar, .tar, .jar, .cer, .cur, etc).