# In Windows, if I type date stamp YYMMDD within file names (or content) can I later search for results within a particular YYDDMM range? How?

Tags: windows-10, search, regex, windows-search, file-search

I use Windows 10. If I use date stamps ( YYMMDD ) within my file names how can I go back and search for  files with names that contain YYMMDD values within a certain range?
If I used the date stamps within the contents of a file and the Windows inbuilt Search capability is able to index the file contents, can I still search for  files that contain YYMMDD values within a certain range.

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a representative sample of the filenames.

Comment: Did you a look at this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/570760/find-filenames-with-certain-pattern-on-windows-command-line?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't.

The only dates Windows search can interpret as actual dates are datemodified, datecreated, ... ([source](http://www.howtogeek.com/243511/how-to-search-for-files-from-a-certain-date-range-in-windows-8-and-10/))

Windows search also doesn't support functions, nor regex. So you can't grab the YYMMDD part and convert it into a date.

If you were to add the YYMMDD into the file contents, it would still only be searched as a string, not as a date.

So, the answer to your specific question, is, unfortunately, no.

Possible workarounds though:

- Write a PowerShell script to list all files containing the YYMMDD pattern, convert it to a date, and apply a filter.
- Write a PowerShell script to update the Creation or Modified date of all files into their YYMMDD timestampt. Once you update those dates, you can use creation/modified date in windows search.